# How can i access into checking the actual values of my pair in this code? Java

Tags: java, arraylist, equals

I want to see if the two `z,y` that make a pair is already exist inside my `ArrayList`. I know that each time I make a new reference of pair and that will be store inside an `ArrayList`. But somehow I want to check the contents `onePair` and if it exist then don't let it add.

**Basically I want unique pairs to be added to my `ArrayList`.**

```
public class Pair {
    public int left;

    public int right;   

    Pair(int left, int right){
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

In some other class:

```
ArrayList<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();
onePair = new Pair(z, y);
if(!pairs.contains(onePair)){
    pairs.add(onePair);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the `boolean equals(Object otherPair)` method (and when you override `equals` you're also supposed to override `int hashCode()`. Also, consider using a `Set` instead of an `ArrayList` so that you don't need to check for duplicates.

```
public class Pair {
  public int left;
  public int right;

  Pair(int left, int right) {
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object otherObj) {
    if (otherObj == null || !(otherObj instanceof Pair)) {
      return false;
    }
    Pair otherPair = (Pair) otherObj;
    return (this.left == otherPair.left && this.right == otherPair.right);
  }
  public int hashCode() {
    return new Integer(this.left).hashCode() + new Integer(this.right).hashCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: You are close, but not quite correct. The method signature should be `boolean equals(Object o)` to override the equals method

Comment: Note: no need to use contains if a `Set` is used

Comment: For more info on why you must override `hashCode` whenever you override `equals`, see [Puzzle 6: "What's in a Name" from the book Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/).

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks! I usually just rely on the IDE for that :)

Comment: @BenTaitelbaum `equals` still seems odd to me (don't even compile I'm sure). Can you correct it?

Comment: @RC. thanks for catching that. I've clearly been away from java too long... :)